# Obtain an upper bound for direction vector

Tags: real-analysis

Denote by $|\cdot|$ the usual Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$ and for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \neq 0$, define
$$U\left(x\right)=\frac x{|x|}.$$
I have found the following upper bound in a paper (Probal Chaudhuri, [Multivariate Location Estimation Using Extension of R-Estimates Through U-Statistics Type Approach](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-20/issue-2/Multivariate-Location-Estimation-Using-Extension-of-R-Estimates-Through-U/10.1214/aos/1176348662.full), Ann. Statist. 20(2): 897-916 (June, 1992), Proof of Lemma 5.3, p.907):
\begin{equation}
 \vert U\left(x+y\right)-U\left(x\right) \vert \leq 2|y|/|x|, y\in \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}
But by using triangle inequality I have obtained the following result.
\begin{equation}
|U(x+y)-U(x)|\le|U(x+y)|+|U(x)|\le2. 
\end{equation}
I was wondering how can I obtain the result that was mentioned in the article.

Comment: Absolute value.

Comment: Sorry, probably I miss understood from the article. It should be an Euclidean norm.

Comment: Multivariate location estimation using extension of R-estimates through U-statistics type approach

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Its $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{equation}
    \left|\frac{x+y}{|x+y|}-\frac{x}{|x|} \right|=\left|\frac{(x+y)(|x|-|x+y|)+y|x+y|}{|x|\,|x+y|}\right|
\end{equation}
Using a triangle inequality and $\left|\, |x|-|y+x| \, \right| \leq |y |$ (the reverse triangle inequality), we derive
\begin{equation}\left|\frac{x+y}{|x+y|}-\frac{x}{|x|} \right|\le
 \frac{|x+y|\left|\,|x| -|x+y|\,\right|+|y||x+y|}{|x|\,|x+y|}\leq \frac{2|y|}{|x|}.
\end{equation}.

Comment: (+1) Note that this holds for any norm, not necessarily Euclidean.

Comment: In the same article, I have another question. On page 907, the author mentioned for any constant M, \begin{equation} \underset{y: |y|\leq M}{\sup}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |x+y|^{-\beta} h\left(x\right)dx<+\infty.\end{equation} I couldn't understand how can I obtain this. @Anne Bauval

Comment: If you have another question, edit another post (and include your thoughts about it, [not just "I have no idea"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)). [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question)